# Any examples of negative ADM energy solutions with WEC but not DEC satisfied?

Tags: general-relativity, energy

Any examples of negative [ADM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ADM_formalism) energy solutions with weak energy condition (WEC) but not dominant energy condition (DEC) satisfied?

Witten's proof of the positive energy theorem requires the dominant energy condition. Is there any counterexample of a metric satisfying the weak energy condition, but not the dominant energy theorem, with negative ADM energy?